# Meteor Accounts autologin pattern?

Tags: security, meteor, autologin, accounts

I'm thinking about a sign-up-with-mobile number system whereby someone can register with a mobile number and get a SMS to verify that they exist... at which point I'd like to have them automatically logged in without a password... (the SMS is basically a password)

This is patterned on the Lyft app sign-up, which doesn't ask for a username/password/etc.

But for the life of me, I can't figure out how to do this.

I'm totally fine with a server only `Meteor.method` which responds with something "secure" but I don't know what that would be now.

The only thing I can think of would be to set the password on the User and then transmit it to the client and run a login (which seems insecure to me).

I have read through this great article
https://meteorhacks.com/extending-meteor-accounts.html
and it's a good option, but I don't know of a strategy for that which wouldn't bypass security too

*(at some point the server has to communicate securely back to the client...)*

Recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

I made a package that might help you, Meteor accounts phone, which do login based on sms mobile number verification https://github.com/okland/accounts-phone/ Enjoy!