# Meteor Accounts Resume Token "Remember Me"

Tags: authentication, meteor, accounts

I'm building a Meteor + Cordova app where I want sign-in to "stick forever" on the mobile device.

I see the following tutorial whereby I can setup my own custom "resume handler"

- https://meteorhacks.com/extending-meteor-accounts.html
- `Accounts.registerLoginHandler`
- `Accounts._generateStampedLoginToken`
- `Accounts._hashStampedToken`

I'll probably write my own (janky) implementation of the above functions and try to get it working, probably storing in localStorage on the client... but I thought I'd ask here to see if anyone knew of a specific solution to this wrapped as package, or a clean example.

Ideally:

- `meteor add xxxxx:rememberme`
- setup

  - `rememberMe.config.days = 9999`
  - `rememberMe.config.storageClient = localStorage`

NOTE: this is related to [Meteor Accounts autologin pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799396/meteor-accounts-autologin-pattern)

Recommendations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using the built-in  Accounts.config(options) http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_config

```
Accounts.config({
   loginExpirationInDays: null
})
```

Once logged in, it will never expire until the user logout again with Meteor.logout();

However, be aware that since the token is stored in localstorage, it get cleaned sometimes automatically by iOS or android

Comment: The "getting cleared out automatically" is what I remember hearing about -- Any way around that?

Anyway - this is the "right" way, I just don't know how to keep it from getting cleared out.

Comment: I dont think it's possible to control the localstorage cleanup by OS. On the other hand, you can make use of the file system api http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.file   . I suppose you can save the token in a file as a backup. So you will normally read the token from localstorage, if the token is not there due to clean up, you can read it from the file.

Comment: That sounds like a great solution... I'll look into it - thanks!

Comment: can you tell me more about the localstorage cleanup by OS... if I were to switch to say WebSQL, would it still get trashed periodically?

Comment: There is a bug apparently (at the time of writing) why this solution won't work anymore, see https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5121

Answer (score 3):

This [mbanting:cordova-accounts-resume](https://atmospherejs.com/mbanting/cordova-accounts-resume) package will help resolve this by saving the loginToken on the file system, to be used if localStorage is cleared out before the app resumes.

Comment: Thanks for that. This is the answer that will actually work on all devices.